# Will my laptop's internal microphone/webcam work if I switch to Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, microphone, webcam, windows-11-v22h2

Recently, I've been wanting to install Arch Linux on my laptop, a HP Victus 15-fb0015nr. But I'm concerned the microphone and webcam will stop working.

Currently, I'm using Windows 11 22H2 build 22621.2428 and it's working just fine, both the microphone and webcam.

Will the internal microphone/webcam stop working after I switch to Arch Linux? I already know how to install it via archinstall.

Edit: Thanks ChanganAuto (I hope I spelled it right) for the quick reply, but...

A. There isn't a GUI in the live environment.

B. There isn't a web browser (at least I think)

C. It's a live environment without drivers. What did you expect?

For some reason, archinstall just would not install Arch to a USB. If you know an Arch Linux live image with a GUI and a web browser, please post the link!

Also, harrymc, the first post you linked to mentioned an NVIDIA GPU, while my laptop has a AMD GPU.

Can someone with a HP Victus 15-fb0015nr laptop (that has a AMD GPU, NOT a NVIDIA GPU.) install Arch Linux on ANY drive and check the webcam/microphone, please. Tell me how it went if you do...

Comment: 1. Nobody can give you an assertive answer without testing it first. Any computer sold with factory installed Windows 11 is too new to have an users' base large enough. 2. If ArchLinux has a live session you can and should try it yourself. 3. Installing as a VM has nothing to do with doing the same in bare metal and inferences CAN'T be made from what works and what doesn't when using virtualization.

Comment: The fact that the Live version failed to work is already a bad sign.

Comment: Dual Booting is proving more and more to be a wanting strategy. I dumped it years ago. Use a Virtual Machine and then (a) the microphone will work, or (b) you can easily try another Linux.

Comment: Also Virtual Machines allow testing in a way not easily done in a dual boot environment and allow you to test multiple operating systems easily

Comment: If you have a solution then post an answer. your question is not a place for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webcam and microphone work on Arch Linux.

I have no issues with brightness or the kernel not starting after sleep as mentioned in the [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1812512/653259).

Comment: You "close" the question yourself by marking the correct answer that helped you solve the problem. Please read the Help section to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

According to some posts about Arch Linux on HP Victus 15,
the hardware support is not great.

[**inverted Brightness and dim in linux while dual booting or live booting linux iso in HP Victus 15.**](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Video-Display-and-Touch/inverted-Brightness-and-dim-in-linux-while-dual-booting-or/td-p/8815996)

Post from ‎07-21-2023 :

> I have faced a significant problem with linux distros on my laptop. I have a HP Victus 15 Gaming Laptop. The configurations are as follows:- Processor:- AMD Ryzen 5 5600H Graphics Card:- Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 Ti The Problem is :- Whenever I booted up into a linux distro, may it be live or from ssd, The Brightness is dimmed. The brightness bar is inverted. Also the max brightness is the dimmed brightness and it cannot be further increased. This was the problem in most of the linux distros in this particular laptop.

[**Kernel not starting after sleep**](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=288711)

From Arch Linux forums on 2023-09-11 :

> I am using kernel version 6.5.2 on an HP Victus 15 (dual booted with windows 11). I got the laptop about two weeks ago and from the first time I slept the laptop, I've been having this problem. After I sleep the laptop and I attempt to wake it (either by pressing buttons on the keyboard or opening the lid), the power button lights up, and after around 5 seconds, the screen turns on (blank screen) for about 5 seconds and then turns off again.

[**Screen brightness does not change on HP Victus 15 fb0000 Laptop**](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=278772)

From Arch Linux BBS forums on 2022-08-10:

> Despite the system registering a change in
>
> ```
> /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness
> ```
>
> there is little to no visible difference in screen brightness. I have
> tried using the brightness keys on the keyboard, the brightnessctl
> program, and directly editing the brightness file.
>
> All 3 methods appear to make only very small changes in the actual
> brightness. The screen is always dark, but 0 is the darkest, 1 is the
> brightest (but not by much) and it slowly gets darker as I go up to
> 255.

After reading this, in your place I would really search for another
Linux distribution.